# Unable fetch data from API in swiftUI through URLSession

Tags: swift

This is my code to fetch the data, I define a class and 2 structs,

```
struct Aude: Codable{
    
    var name: String
    var username: String
    var avatar_path: String
    var rating: Int?
    
}
struct RevInfo: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id: String
    var author: String
    var created_at: String
    var author_details: Aude
    var content: String
    
}
class getReview: ObservableObject {
  // 1.
    @Published var todos = [RevInfo]()
    init() {
        self.idStr = idStr
        let url = URL(string: "https://hw9node-310902.uc.r.appspot.com/moviereviews/24428" )!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let todoData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([RevInfo].self, from: todoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.todos = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The json I want to get is below, it is an array of RevInfo, and each RevInfo contains a Aude

```
[{
      "author":"Gimly",
      "author_details":{
         "name":"Gimly",
         "username":"Ruuz",
         "avatar_path":"/xUObnJSvHrFPsIpoDmb1jiQZLq7.jpg",
         "rating":9
      },
      "content":"**A long format...",
      "created_at":"2017-10-27T02:47:35.267Z",
      "id":"59f29e47c3a3687126003ccd",
      "updated_at":"2017-10-27T15:59:53.935Z",
      "url":"https://www.themoviedb.org/review/59f29e47c3a3687126003ccd"
   },
   {
      "author":"Per Gunnar Jonsson",
      "author_details":{
         "name":"Per Gunnar Jonsson",
         "username":"Dark Jedi",
        "avatar_path":"/https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/cbabaea0fa98692d00130498d7ac5d7c.jpg",
         "rating":null
      },
      "content":"After the recent ...",
      "created_at":"2018-01-22T06:06:56.333Z",
      "id":"5a657f809251410b2d030491",
      "updated_at":"2018-01-22T22:36:05.204Z",
      "url":"https://www.themoviedb.org/review/5a657f809251410b2d030491"
   }
...
]
```

I find the problem possibly come from `var author_details: Aude`  and the define of the struct `Aude` because I can get the data if deleting  `var author_details: Aude`  but I need to use the rating property of `Aude` . Can someone help me

Comment: Rather than meaningless literal "Error" print the real `error`.

Answer (score 0):

In response avatar_path in author_details can be null. So make avatar_path in Aude struct optional.

Comment: I just solved it by making the rating property optional, as the avatar_path is useless in my project I jus ignore it. But anyway, thank you for helping me